# Problem with the behavior of org-fontify-done-headline

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, fonts, todo

I want entries with the `DONE` status to be greyed out, so in my init file I have

`(setq org-fontify-done-headline t)`

and I have added

```
 '(org-headline-done 
   ((((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) 
     (:foreground "dim gray"))))
```

to `custom-set-faces`.

It works very well in the org file itself. However, when I display an entry in a custom agenda view (with `org-agenda-custom-commands`) with another status (say, `TODO`), and that there are checkboxes below the headline of the entry in question, the entry will be greyed out if at least one of the checkboxes is left unchecked, but will not be greyed out if all the checkboxes are checked.

I have no idea where to search to find a fix for this weird behavior.